# Set up my own DNS server

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003

I have my own registered domain. I want to set up my own DNS server and host a website completely independent of any third party hosting service.

I have Windows Server 2003 and have installed the DNS role and configured it with a single forward zone (I am new to this terminology and am not sure if I am using it correctly). Lets say my domain is xyz.com I have the DNS role set up for xyz.com as the domain with a forward lookup zone. Also, I have reserved an internal IP to my server using the router's DHCP reservation list. So I basically have a static IP for my server on the internal network.

How do I go about setting up this infrastructure so that I can have my own DNS set up and host my website ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few more things you need to do:

The DNS you set up will only work within your network. What about folks who will want to connect to your website from Internet?
Moreover, your infrastructure should have at least a static public ip address assigned so that it could be accessible from Internet (if you're behind a router you should create a rule based on the port of DNS queries so that any requests to a public ip address with a port id 53 are routed to your DNS server).

I have not personally done this, but these are things you should consider when setting up this infrastructure. Hope this helps!

Besides that you should also set up a web server that will host your website. You can use IIS on your Win2K3 server or install an open-source Apache server. The first thing you'll need to do is to specify bindings and then create the relevant rules on your router.

For example HTTP queries work on port 80, so any request submitted to your public ip address with port id 80 should be routed to your web server.

You can host both DNS and web server roles on the same machine, though. Queries will have different ports and will be processed accordingly.